# luaL_newstate doesn't succeed under valgrind?

Tags: lua, valgrind, luajit

I'm trying to debug some problems with a luajit based application under 64bit Linux.

The script calls back into a number of libraries via FFI and I'm trying to figure out some memory corruption issues.  Valgrind is normally my tool of choice for this, however I've found that luaL_newstate fails when run under Valgrind.

After some poking around I found that standard luajit also fails to load.  I think this might be more a problem with valgrind than luajit.  Is there a way of giving valgrind more memory?

Comment: What version of valgrind are you using? Versions between 3.9.0 and 3.11.0 appear to be broken on x86_64 with luajit. See [here](http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/table-overflow-and-not-enough-memory-errors-LuaJIT-21-exec-on-x86-64,1).

Comment: Thanks Etan, 3.10.  I'll attempt an upgrade and see if that helps.

Comment: Downloaded latest and installed from source.  Problem gone.  Thanks @EtanReisner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a version of valgrind starting with version 3.9.0 and up to (but not including) version 3.11.0 that is likely the problem.

Those versions appear to be "broken" on x86_64 with luajit.

See [this email](http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/table-overflow-and-not-enough-memory-errors-LuaJIT-21-exec-on-x86-64,1) from Mike Pall:

> [Note that Valgrind 3.9.0 has chosen to block MAP_32BIT, which
>   breaks LuaJIT on Linux/x64:
>
> https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=324181
>
> Older versions of Valgrind still work. It wasn't that useful to
>   debug LuaJIT on x64, anyway, due to the mandatory use of the
>   builtin allocator. But none of that relates to your problem.]